# Injection from $[0,1]$ to power set of Natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I heard it's possible via "binary expression" and even more, for arbitrary intervals in $\mathbb{R}$.

Any one cam tell me how to construct above binary correspondence?

Comment: For a real number $r$ in the interval in binary decimal expansion, if the $n$'th decimal is $1$, then we let $n\in A_r$, with compensations for dual representations.

Answer (score 1):

First note that all closed intervals have bijections between them: just use affine maps:
$f[0,1] \rightarrow [a,b]: f(x)= (b-a)x + a$ is a bijection.

So if $i: [0,1]\to \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is an injection, then $[a,b]$ embeds via $i \circ f^{-1}$. Open and half-open intervals embed because they're contained in closed intervals and we use the restricted injections.

We can take care of infinite intervals using functions like $\arctan(x)$ etc.

We can indeed map $[0,1]$ into the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$ using binary expansions, so write $x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n 2^n$ with $a_n \in \{0,1\}$, and if there is some $N$ such that $a_N = 0$ and $a_n =1$ for $n > N$ use the other representation with $a_N =1$ and $a_n = 0$ for $ n > N$.(this is to ensure there is a unique image; note that $1$ has all $a_n = 1, n \ge 1$ has only one).
Then map $x$ to the set $i(x) = \{n: x_n = 1\} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$.
This defines an injection as two distinct points cannot have the same expansion.
$i(0) = \emptyset, i(1) = \mathbb{N}, i({1 \over 2}) = \{1\}$ etc.